# Specs for local-state queries

Tags: ledger, ouroboros

Does anyone know where I can find on-the-wire specs / cddl for the ledger-specific payloads of the local-state queries?

I have the specs for the top-level state-machine messages of the polymorphic request-response Ouroboros mini-protocol, but I can't find the specs for the concrete queries.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [Cardano.Api.Query](https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-node/cardano-api/lib/Cardano-Api-Query.html).

Comment: Link is dead now.